# Demo DocuSign Click API - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset

Tags: docusignapi

We're currently integrating with the DocuSign click API and when we call `clickapi/v1/accounts/<accountId>/clickwraps?status=active` we are seeing intermittent connection issues. We're getting a `Connection reset; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset` error. For some background, we also call the `/oauth/token` API and that call usually succeeds, just not the following call to the click API.

- Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
- Not a rate limiting issue
- This error only occurs when using the demo account, this is not something we've seen using the prod account.
- Running automated tests is usually when we see this issue, when we call the click API a few times in a row

Could someone provide any insight into what the cause might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only requirements that I'm aware of for our REST Apis are that traffic be sent on a secure channel using a TLS version higher than 1.1. If you're presently using a higher TLS version and are connecting to Demo using https, there's likely something else going on.

You should be able to use a utility like WireShark or Fiddler to capture the network traffic and see what's happening in the background. If you can, try to reproduce this and then send the resulting network log to matt.king@docusign.com and we'll have a closer look.

For Fiddler with Java: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp